# Django Mongo SQLDecodeError at /admin/

Tags: python, django, mongodb, python-3.x, pymongo

I have been experimenting with mongodb with Django. I created a super user, and then proceeded to http://localhost:8000/admin/ to login. Upon entering my credentials, and submitting them, the error given at the end of this post occurred. I have 2 other apps in this project and have also commented the line where the admin can register the model in `appname/admin.py`, i.e.:

```
#admin.site.register(Tweet)
```

How can I fix this?
If you would like any further information about the code or from certain files please let me know and I will edit it in :)

I assume the error is caused with the way mongo and django is workign together but have no idea how to correct it.

I am sure the python installation, and routes all work correctly as they were configured with the assistance of the department admins.

**NOTE:** some of the routes are due to custom installation of Python in case it seems extremely weird. I am using a Department machine to do my work, hence the paths.

Relevant Versions of modules/software:

[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-16)] on linux

- python (3.6.4)
- Django (2.0.3)
- MongoDB shell version: (2.6.12)
- mongod --version results in: db version v2.6.12
- pymongo (3.6.1)
- sqlparse (0.2.4)
- djongo (1.2.23)

Db code in `settings.py`:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'djongo',
        'NAME': 'hamish-djongo-db',
        'USER': 'hamish_admin',
        'PASSWORD': 'thishasbeencensoredfortheinternet',
    }
}
```

### Error in shell:

```
Internal Server Error: /admin/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/dcs/14/u1404526/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/djongo/sql2mongo/query.py", line 454, in __iter__
    yield from iter(self._query)
  File "/dcs/14/u1404526/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/djongo/sql2mongo/query.py", line 144, in __iter__
    self._cursor = self._get_cursor()
  File "/dcs/14/u1404526/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/djongo/sql2mongo/query.py", line 229, in _get_cursor
    cur = self.db_ref[self.left_table].aggregate(pipeline)
  File "/dcs/14/u1404526/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/collection.py", line 2185, in aggregate
    **kwargs)
  File "/dcs/14/u1404526/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/collection.py", line 2092, in _aggregate
    client=self.__database.client)
  File "/dcs/14/u1404526/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/pool.py", line 517, in command
    collation=collation)
  File "/dcs/14/u1404526/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/network.py", line 125, in command
    parse_write_concern_error=parse_write_concern_error)
  File "/dcs/14/u1404526/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/helpers.py", line 145, in _check_command_response
    raise OperationFailure(msg % errmsg, code, response)
pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: exception: Unrecognized pipeline stage name: '$lookup'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/dcs/14/u1404526/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 35, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/dcs/14/u1404526/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 158, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/dcs/14/u1404526/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 156, in _get_response
    response = response.render()
  File "/dcs/14/u1404526/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/response.py", line 106, in render
    self.content = self.rendered_content
  File "/dcs/14/u1404526/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/response.py", line 83, in rendered_content
    content = template.render(context, self._request)
  File "/dcs/14/u1404526/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 61, in render
    return self.template.render(context)
  File "/dcs/14/u1404526/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 175, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "/dcs/14/u1404526/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 167, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/dcs/14/u1404526/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 943, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/dcs/14/u1404526/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 910, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/dcs/14/u1404526/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 155, in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context)
  File "/dcs/14/u1404526/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 167, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/dcs/14/u1404526/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 943, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/dcs/14/u1404526/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 910, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/dcs/14/u1404526/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 155, in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context)
  File "/dcs/14/u1404526/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 167, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/dcs/14/u1404526/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 943, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/dcs/14/u1404526/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 910, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/dcs/14/u1404526/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 67, in render
    result = block.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/dcs/14/u1404526/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 943, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/dcs/14/u1404526/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 910, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/dcs/14/u1404526/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 314, in render
    return nodelist.render(context)
  File "/dcs/14/u1404526/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 943, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/dcs/14/u1404526/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 910, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/dcs/14/u1404526/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 168, in render
    len_values = len(values)
  File "/dcs/14/u1404526/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 254, in __len__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "/dcs/14/u1404526/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1179, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
  File "/dcs/14/u1404526/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 62, in __iter__
    for row in compiler.results_iter(results):
  File "/dcs/14/u1404526/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1460, in cursor_iter
    for rows in iter((lambda: cursor.fetchmany(itersize)), sentinel):
  File "/dcs/14/u1404526/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1460, in <lambda>
    for rows in iter((lambda: cursor.fetchmany(itersize)), sentinel):
  File "/dcs/14/u1404526/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 96, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/dcs/14/u1404526/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/djongo/cursor.py", line 59, in fetchmany
    ret.append(self.result.next())
  File "/dcs/14/u1404526/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/djongo/sql2mongo/query.py", line 448, in __next__
    return next(self._result_generator)
  File "/dcs/14/u1404526/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/djongo/sql2mongo/query.py", line 466, in __iter__
    raise exe from e
djongo.sql2mongo.SQLDecodeError: FAILED SQL: SELECT "django_admin_log"."id", "django_admin_log"."action_time", "django_admin_log"."user_id", "django_admin_log"."content_type_id", "django_admin_log"."object_id", "django_admin_log"."object_repr", "django_admin_log"."action_flag", "django_admin_log"."change_message", "auth_user"."id", "auth_user"."password", "auth_user"."last_login", "auth_user"."is_superuser", "auth_user"."username", "auth_user"."first_name", "auth_user"."last_name", "auth_user"."email", "auth_user"."is_staff", "auth_user"."is_active", "auth_user"."date_joined", "django_content_type"."id", "django_content_type"."app_label", "django_content_type"."model" FROM "django_admin_log" INNER JOIN "auth_user" ON ("django_admin_log"."user_id" = "auth_user"."id") LEFT OUTER JOIN "django_content_type" ON ("django_admin_log"."content_type_id" = "django_content_type"."id") WHERE "django_admin_log"."user_id" = %(0)s ORDER BY "django_admin_log"."action_time" DESC LIMIT 10
Pymongo error: OrderedDict([('errmsg', "exception: Unrecognized pipeline stage name: '$lookup'"), ('code', 16436), ('ok', 0.0)])
Version: 1.2.23
[29/Mar/2018 12:42:09] "GET /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 500 339290
```

### Error on page:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/admin/

Django Version: 2.0.3
Python Version: 3.6.4
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'widget_tweaks',
 'blogtest',
 'tweetish']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']


Template error:
In template /dcs/14/u1404526/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/base.html, error at line 0
   FAILED SQL: SELECT "django_admin_log"."id", "django_admin_log"."action_time", "django_admin_log"."user_id", "django_admin_log"."content_type_id", "django_admin_log"."object_id", "django_admin_log"."object_repr", "django_admin_log"."action_flag", "django_admin_log"."change_message", "auth_user"."id", "auth_user"."password", "auth_user"."last_login", "auth_user"."is_superuser", "auth_user"."username", "auth_user"."first_name", "auth_user"."last_name", "auth_user"."email", "auth_user"."is_staff", "auth_user"."is_active", "auth_user"."date_joined", "django_content_type"."id", "django_content_type"."app_label", "django_content_type"."model" FROM "django_admin_log" INNER JOIN "auth_user" ON ("django_admin_log"."user_id" = "auth_user"."id") LEFT OUTER JOIN "django_content_type" ON ("django_admin_log"."content_type_id" = "django_content_type"."id") WHERE "django_admin_log"."user_id" = %(0)s ORDER BY "django_admin_log"."action_time" DESC LIMIT 10
Pymongo error: OrderedDict([('errmsg', "exception: Unrecognized pipeline stage name: '$lookup'"), ('code', 16436), ('ok', 0.0)])
Version: 1.2.23
   1 : {% load i18n static %}<!DOCTYPE html>
   2 : {% get_current_language as LANGUAGE_CODE %}{% get_current_language_bidi as LANGUAGE_BIDI %}
   3 : <html lang="{{ LANGUAGE_CODE|default:"en-us" }}" {% if LANGUAGE_BIDI %}dir="rtl"{% endif %}>
   4 : <head>
   5 : <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
   6 : <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% block stylesheet %}{% static "admin/css/base.css" %}{% endblock %}" />
   7 : {% block extrastyle %}{% endblock %}
   8 : {% if LANGUAGE_BIDI %}<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% block stylesheet_rtl %}{% static "admin/css/rtl.css" %}{% endblock %}" />{% endif %}
   9 : {% block extrahead %}{% endblock %}
   10 : {% block responsive %}


Traceback:

File "/dcs/14/u1404526/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/djongo/sql2mongo/query.py" in __iter__
  454.             yield from iter(self._query)

File "/dcs/14/u1404526/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/djongo/sql2mongo/query.py" in __iter__
  144.             self._cursor = self._get_cursor()

File "/dcs/14/u1404526/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/djongo/sql2mongo/query.py" in _get_cursor
  229.             cur = self.db_ref[self.left_table].aggregate(pipeline)

File "/dcs/14/u1404526/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/collection.py" in aggregate
  2185.                                    **kwargs)

File "/dcs/14/u1404526/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/collection.py" in _aggregate
  2092.                 client=self.__database.client)

File "/dcs/14/u1404526/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/pool.py" in command
  517.                            collation=collation)

File "/dcs/14/u1404526/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/network.py" in command
  125.                 parse_write_concern_error=parse_write_concern_error)

File "/dcs/14/u1404526/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/helpers.py" in _check_command_response
  145.             raise OperationFailure(msg % errmsg, code, response)

The above exception (exception: Unrecognized pipeline stage name: '$lookup') was the direct cause of the following exception:

File "/dcs/14/u1404526/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  35.             response = get_response(request)

File "/dcs/14/u1404526/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  158.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/dcs/14/u1404526/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  156.                 response = response.render()

File "/dcs/14/u1404526/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/response.py" in render
  106.             self.content = self.rendered_content

File "/dcs/14/u1404526/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/response.py" in rendered_content
  83.         content = template.render(context, self._request)

File "/dcs/14/u1404526/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py" in render
  61.             return self.template.render(context)

File "/dcs/14/u1404526/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  175.                     return self._render(context)

File "/dcs/14/u1404526/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  167.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "/dcs/14/u1404526/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  943.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "/dcs/14/u1404526/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  910.             return self.render(context)

File "/dcs/14/u1404526/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  155.             return compiled_parent._render(context)

File "/dcs/14/u1404526/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  167.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "/dcs/14/u1404526/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  943.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "/dcs/14/u1404526/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  910.             return self.render(context)

File "/dcs/14/u1404526/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  155.             return compiled_parent._render(context)

File "/dcs/14/u1404526/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  167.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "/dcs/14/u1404526/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  943.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "/dcs/14/u1404526/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  910.             return self.render(context)

File "/dcs/14/u1404526/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  67.                 result = block.nodelist.render(context)

File "/dcs/14/u1404526/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  943.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "/dcs/14/u1404526/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  910.             return self.render(context)

File "/dcs/14/u1404526/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py" in render
  314.                 return nodelist.render(context)

File "/dcs/14/u1404526/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  943.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "/dcs/14/u1404526/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  910.             return self.render(context)

File "/dcs/14/u1404526/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py" in render
  168.             len_values = len(values)

File "/dcs/14/u1404526/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in __len__
  254.         self._fetch_all()

File "/dcs/14/u1404526/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in _fetch_all
  1179.             self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))

File "/dcs/14/u1404526/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in __iter__
  62.         for row in compiler.results_iter(results):

File "/dcs/14/u1404526/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in cursor_iter
  1460.         for rows in iter((lambda: cursor.fetchmany(itersize)), sentinel):

File "/dcs/14/u1404526/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in <lambda>
  1460.         for rows in iter((lambda: cursor.fetchmany(itersize)), sentinel):

File "/dcs/14/u1404526/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py" in inner
  96.                 return func(*args, **kwargs)

File "/dcs/14/u1404526/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/djongo/cursor.py" in fetchmany
  59.                 ret.append(self.result.next())

File "/dcs/14/u1404526/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/djongo/sql2mongo/query.py" in __next__
  448.         return next(self._result_generator)

File "/dcs/14/u1404526/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/djongo/sql2mongo/query.py" in __iter__
  466.             raise exe from e

Exception Type: SQLDecodeError at /admin/
Exception Value: FAILED SQL: SELECT "django_admin_log"."id", "django_admin_log"."action_time", "django_admin_log"."user_id", "django_admin_log"."content_type_id", "django_admin_log"."object_id", "django_admin_log"."object_repr", "django_admin_log"."action_flag", "django_admin_log"."change_message", "auth_user"."id", "auth_user"."password", "auth_user"."last_login", "auth_user"."is_superuser", "auth_user"."username", "auth_user"."first_name", "auth_user"."last_name", "auth_user"."email", "auth_user"."is_staff", "auth_user"."is_active", "auth_user"."date_joined", "django_content_type"."id", "django_content_type"."app_label", "django_content_type"."model" FROM "django_admin_log" INNER JOIN "auth_user" ON ("django_admin_log"."user_id" = "auth_user"."id") LEFT OUTER JOIN "django_content_type" ON ("django_admin_log"."content_type_id" = "django_content_type"."id") WHERE "django_admin_log"."user_id" = %(0)s ORDER BY "django_admin_log"."action_time" DESC LIMIT 10
Pymongo error: OrderedDict([('errmsg', "exception: Unrecognized pipeline stage name: '$lookup'"), ('code', 16436), ('ok', 0.0)])
Version: 1.2.23
```

Comment: `$lookup` pipeline stage is [new in Mongo 3.2](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/index.html)

Comment: Here is the **solution** for: [djongo.sql2mongo.SQLDecodeError](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57567335/9049379)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks to @oluwafemi-sule comment, the problem has been corrected.

I have updated to Mongo 3.6.3 to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try upgrading Django to version 3.1.7 or above. I got an SQLDecodeError when I tried to migrate and I solved it by upgrading Django and running makemigrations again before migrating. The previous Django version that I had was 2.1.7 and apparently the migration file generated by these two versions are very different.

Answer (score 0):

I downgraded my django version to 3.2 and it worked for me.

```
pip install django==3.2
```

Answer (score -3):

Error: "djongo.sql2mongo.SQLDecodeError: **FAILED SQL**: SELECT"

Solution: Here you can simply see that SQL is failed, hence first install mysqlclient and then run the command.

> sudo apt-get install mysql-client

Reason: Pymongo wants to convert sql(Default query language) query to mongoDB query but unable to process it because of missing mysql pluggins.