# How to solve SQLdecode error when you migrate models in django?

Tags: python, django, mongodb, django-models, django-migrations

I am new to django, I have created a project and app and I would like to connect my project to the mongodb. when I enter `python manage.py migrate` command , I am getting below mentioned error.

I have dropped database and cleared all migrations in the django_migration table and deleted migration files in the created migrations folder. Still getting same error.

Please help me with this. Thanks in advance

Error:

```
    raise TypeError("documents must be a non-empty list")
TypeError: documents must be a non-empty list
```

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

```
djongo.sql2mongo.SQLDecodeError: FAILED SQL: INSERT INTO "django_migrations" ("app", "name", "applied") VALUES (%(0)s, %(1)s, %(2)s)
    Version: 1.2.31
```

Settings.py

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'djongo',
        'NAME': 'DB_name',
        'HOST':'localhost',
        # 'PORT': 27017,
        # 'USER':'',
        # 'PASSWORD':''
    },
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class dummy(models.Model):

    name= models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null= True)
```

Comment: The actual `TypeError: documents must be a non-empty list` is from the pymongo driver and means what it says, as it got an "empty list" when it expected input. Did you actually run a `python manage.py makemigrations` first? Because the error seems to indicate there's "nothing to do". You said you "deleted", but AFIAK you still need to run the `makemigrations` first.

Comment: I did `python manage.py makemigrations`  first then run `python manage.py migrate` , still no luck

Answer (score 9):

After creating django project uninstall **sqlparse** by typing

```
pip3 uninstall sqlparse
```

Then install sqlparse version=0.2.4 by typing

```
pip3 install sqlparse==0.2.4
```

Then migrate mongodb database by typing

```
python3 manage.py migrate
```

If you are using **python2** then use (**pip**) instead of (**pip3**) and (**python**) instead of (**python3**) in the command.

Answer (score 3):

I have solved this problem. The problem may be the version of sqlparse - sqlparse 0.2.4 works well, but sqlparse 0.3.0 not. Use following command:

```
pip install sqlparse==0.2.4 --user
```

Comment: Did this and worked. But what is saw -if I do understand well- is install last version of sqlpars. I think this because the output
`Collecting sqlparse==0.2.4
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/65/85/20bdd72f4537cf2c4d5d005368d502b2f464ede22982e724a82c86268eda/sqlparse-0.2.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: sqlparse
Successfully installed sqlparse-0.3.1`

Answer (score 3):

I have updated djongo with `pip install --upgrade djongo` and I have done the migrations `python manage.py migrate --fake-initial` and it has been fixed.

Comment: Thanks it worked !!! , the problem in on djongo , not sqlprase

Answer (score 0):

Just install `sqlprase` to solve this.

Download it
[github sqlprase](https://github.com/andialbrecht/sqlparse/releases)

```
pip install filename.zip
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `python manage.py migrate --fake-initial` the first time you migrate your project.

In setting.py add 

`INSTALLED_APPS=[
'APP_NAME.apps.APP_NAMEConfig',
...,
...,
]`

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it that way `sqlparse==0.2.4` and `djongo==1.3.3` and `django==2.1.7`

Answer (score 0):

**Please try to install the sqlparse package, using this command in the terminal.**

```
 pip install sqlparse==0.2.4
```

Answer (score -1):

I have the same issue with u, I tried with sqlite3 as the database, and the data is just like this:

[image]

so the data is not empty!!

And I tried to change the sql command as follow(line 760 at sql2mongo\query.py):

```
statement = statement[0]
    sm_type = statement.get_type()
    if sm_type=='INSERT':
        self._sql = 'INSERT INTO "django_migrations" ("app", "name", "applied") VALUES ("test", "windy", "2019-03-15 12:00")'
```

but still failed.